# Question about finite dimensional vector space over a field $K$ and free $K[x]$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, free-modules

[image]
I came across questions in the free module section of my abstract algebra text. In the text, the notation $End_{R}(V)$ denotes the set of all $R$-module endomorphisms of $M$. [Algebra: Abstract and Concrete, exercise 8.1.9 on p358 in the attached picture of the linked text](http://homepage.math.uiowa.edu/%7Egoodman/algebrabook.dir/book.2.6.pdf) Onto the question:

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over a field $K$.  Let $T\in End_{K}(V)$.  Give $V$ the corresponding $K[x]$-module structure defined by $\sum_{i} \alpha_{i}x^{i}v=\sum_{i}\alpha_{i}T^{i}(v).$  Show that $V$ is not free as a $K[x]$-module.

In this question, I don't understand how in $\sum_{i} \alpha_{i}x^{i}v=\sum_{i}\alpha_{i}T^{i}(v).$ affects whether $V$ can be a free $K[x]$-module.  If I take a finite basis $B$ for $V$, where $B=\{v_1, v_2,...v_n\}$,  with coefficients $\alpha_i \in K$, then would it be that each of the $\alpha_i x^i v_{i}$ term in the identity $\alpha_i x^i v_{i} = \alpha_{i}T^{i}(v_i)$, the coefficients $\alpha_{i}$ or $\alpha_{i}x^{i}$ might not equal to zero?  Actually, I am assuming the $v$ in the definition $\alpha_i x^i v = \alpha_{i}T^{i}(v)$ refers to basis elements from $B$, but I am not sure where the $x^{i}$ is suppose to come from.  Is it from the vector space $V$ or from the field $K$ along with the $\alpha_i$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm assuming $V$ is finite dimensional over $K$? The word 'finite' seems to be missing from the quoted text.

Comment: @Servaes I edited my post with a hyperlink to the book.  Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: I don't see the quoted text on page 352 of the linked text. Also, could you answer my question in my previous comment?

Comment: @Servaes I typed the question correctly.  I attached a screenshot of it along with the corrected page number.  The page number I cited is from an earlier verion of the author's text.  My apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot, that clarifies the matter (the word 'finite' is missing in your quote).

Comment: @Servaes ops my bad.   I really did made a typo.  My profuse apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the statement $x^i$ means neither an element of $V$ nor $K$. Let me explain the situation: $V$ is a $K$-vector space, so in particular is an abelian group. This means that we can turn $V$ into a module over the ring $R := K[x]$ by specifying what $p \cdot v$ is for each $p \in K[x]$ and $v \in V$ (and then checking that the right identities are satisfied). Recall that $K[x]$ is just the set of all polynomials in the *formal variable* $x$ and with coefficients in $K$. So then this is what your book does: for any polynomial $p = \sum_i \alpha_i x^i \in K[x]$ and any $v \in V$, we declare that
$$
p \cdot v := \sum_i \alpha_i T^i(v).
$$
Since $T^i(v)$ is again a vector in $V$ for each $i$ and this is a finite sum, the result $p \cdot v$ is again an element of $V$, and so we have a well-defined module action.

---

Now that we know what the module structure is (and in particular that $x$ is a formal variable), we can think about the question: we are supposed to show that $V$ is not a free $K[x]$-module. Well, suppose $V$ was free (as a $K[x]$-module) with basis $\mathcal{B} := \{v_1, \ldots, v_n\} \subset V$. From linear algebra (the Cayley-Hamilton theorem) we know that every $T \in \operatorname{End}_K(V)$ is a root of its own (nonzero) characteristic polynomial $p \in K[x]$. Thus $p \cdot v_1 = p(T)(v_1) = 0$, which violates the fact that $\mathcal{B}$ is supposedly $K[x]$-linearly indepedent. Hence the $K[x]$-basis $\mathcal{B}$ cannot exist.

---

Finally let's address the question of why the action of $K[x]$ on $V$ matters for freeness. The point is that to check freeness of $V$ as a $K[x]$-module we need to check that any basis $\mathcal{B} \subset V$ is both spanning and linearly indepednent *over $K[x]$!* As you can see above for any $T \in \operatorname{End}_K(V)$ we can always find a $p \in K[x]$ such that $p \cdot v = 0$ for all $v \in V$, which implies that a basis for $V$ over $K[x]$ can never exist. On the other hand if we wanted to consider $V$ as an ordinary $K$-module of course $V$ does have a basis (indeed, many) since this is just what it means to be an ordinary basis for a vector space over $K$.

Note that any ordinary $K$-basis $\mathcal{B}$ for $V$ is $K$-spanning so of course is $K[x]$-spanning too, but the above implies that such a basis couldn't be $K[x]$-linearly independent.

Comment: @BenWest Of course you are right: no, I have fixed it and simplified things.

Comment: the element $v$ in $T$ denotes basis element from $V$. So if I have a vector space over a field $K$, which is a free module by default then I have another ring act on it, I could undo its status being a free module.  That just seem like some kind of math version Harry Potter magic.

Comment: also this question came before the section on jordan canonical form in the text, I am not sure the author expects the reader to interpret it using matrices.  Same for my other questions that I recently posted.   I am just wondering how you managed to see the connection.

Comment: @SethMai Well, the way I would think about it is that when we equip the set $V$ with two different module structures, one with a $K$-action and one with a $K[x]$-action, we formally just get two different modules which we (somewhat confusingly) both denote again by $V$. It's fine if one of these two different modules is free while the other is not.

Comment: @SethMai Sorry, maybe I'm overlooking something I wrote but I don't quite see where the Jordan canonical form comes into play? Before you have time to come back and explain I might guess that you are referring to my talk of the characteristic polynomial of $T$? In this case I have two comments: (1) In fact the determinant/therefore characteristic polynomial can be defined without reference to any matrices at all, so in this sense we don't need them, and...

Comment: (2) Actually my appeal to the Cayley-Hamilton theorem is a higher-power result than we need. There is instead a direct argument which goes by just counting dimensions: if we know that $\dim \operatorname{End}_K(V) = (\dim V)^2 = n^2$ then we also know that the powers $1, T, T^2, \cdots, T^{n^2}$ cannot all be linearly independent (the powers are a set of $n^2 + 1$ elements of $\operatorname{End}_K(V)$. So, there is a relation of linear dependence between them, and if we replace all of the $T$s with the formal variable $x$ then we again get a polynomial $p$ so that $p(T) = 0$.

Comment: (Of course the degree of $p$ *a priori* might be $> n$ according to this argument, which is never the case by e.g. Cayley-Hamilton, but we don't need this strengthening in our argument.)

Comment: the book talk about the minimal polynomial in the context of rational and jordan canonical form in section 8.6.  It discusses in more detail regarding $\sum_{i} \alpha_{i}x^{i}v=\sum_{i}\alpha_{i}T^{i}(v)$ there.  I really got confused what and where $x^i$ belong to, since  I thought $v$ serve as a basis element for $V$.  Also, the fact there is an increasing power in $T$, do I have to use property of $V$ having some sort of cyclical property.

Comment: @SethMai Ah, I see! Well yes if you like my argument in (2) is basically the same as showing the existence of the minimal polynomial. (It shows that there is some polynomial $p$ for which $p(T) = 0$, and it is then not so difficult to prove that there must be one of minimal degree!)

Comment: @SethMai As for the notation $T^i(v)$, not to worry this makes sense for any linear map $T : V \to V$ and positive integer $i$. We just define $T^1(v) = T(v)$, $T^2(v) = T(T(V))$, $T^3(v) = T(T(T(v)))$, and so forth.

Comment: the way the author defines $\sum_{i} \alpha_{i}x^{i}v=\sum_{i}\alpha_{i}T^{i}(v)$, why can't he just define it as $\sum_{i} \alpha_{i}v_{i}=\sum_{i}\alpha_{i}T^{i}(v_{i})$, this way, just use $v_{i}$ as basis elements for $V$.  Maybe it has to do with the way minimal polynomials are defined, if so, it has been long time since I ever had to use one to solve any math problems.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132132/discussion-between-keeley-hoek-and-seth-mai).

Answer (score 2):

And $R$-module $M$ is *free* if it has a subset $S\subset M$ that generates $M$ *over $R$*, and that is linearly independent *over $R$*. The $R$-module structure of $M$ matters here: For this particular $K[x]$-module structure on $V$, even any singleton is not linearly independent, because for $f\in K[x]$ and $v\in V$
$$f\cdot v=0\qquad\not\Longrightarrow\qquad f=0.$$
That is to say, for every $v\in V$ there exists some nonzero $f\in K[x]$, say $f=\sum_i\alpha_ix^i$, such that
$$0=f\cdot v=(f(T))(v)=\sum_i\alpha_iT^i(v).$$
In fact, a much stronger claim can be made; there exists some nonzero $f\in K[x]$ such that $f\cdot v=0$ for all $v\in V$. This is a polynomial in $K[X]$ that satisfies $(f(T))(v)=0$ for all $v\in V$, or equivalently, that satisfies $f(T)=0$. This is of course the minimal polynomial of $T$, or any multiple of it.

Anyway, we see that the only subset of $V$ that is $K[x]$-linearly independent (w.r.t. this particular $K[x]$-module structure) is the empty set. In particular $V$ is free over $K[x]$ if and only if $V=0$.